# Export to csv options using Numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, file-format, csv, iwork-numbers

I'm using Numbers on my Mac at the moment and exporting to a CSV file. Is there a way to enclose every value with ""?

For example I'm getting the csv file like this:

> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

When I want it like this:

> "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"

I've tried doing this in Excel for mac too but haven't had much luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Excel, you can use CONCATENATE() function to enclose values with double quotation marks. Let's say your values are ranged from A1 to A9.

Set cell B1 as `"`.

Now you can enter the following formula in cell C1:

```
=CONCATENATE($B$1,A1,$B$1)
```

When you drag that cell till C9, you'll have all your values enclosed with double quotation marks. Then you can save your worksheet as a CSV file.

PS: Using `=CONCATENATE(""",A1,""")` does not work here.

Comment: You can use =CONCATENATE("""",A1,"""") - (4 x ") - still hacky but more simple.

Answer (score 1):

For Excel, you can use Earl Kiosterud's [Text Write program](http://www.smokeylake.com/excel/text_write_program.htm):

> The Text Write Program is a Microsoft
>   Excel workbook with a macro program
>   that writes any sheet of any open
>   workbook to a text file with lots of
>   options.
>
> Theses options are:
>
> ```
> File Name to write
> Record Delimiter:     Code/Character  13,10
> Stop if Record Delimiter found in cell?:  Yes
> Field Delimiter:  Code/Character  , (comma)
> Bracketing Code/Character (text qualifier):   " (quotation mark)
> Bracket data fields?:     Yes
>   Bracket blank fields also?:     No
> Skip blank rows?:     No
> Write entire sheet?:  Yes
>      If no, Expand selection?:    No
>      If no, write rectangular?:   No
> ```

Comment: Thanks however this uses VBA which isn't compatible with Excel for mac :(

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use replace function of a lot of programs (I recommend MS Word or Notepad++ because yoy can replace also special characters like carrier return).

In that case, you can simply replace all ocurrences of

,

with

","

And finally putting " in the beginning and the end of text.

Answer (score 0):

if you require quotes then chances are you have commas in the fields which is why you are enclosing them in quotes. Doing a Replace on all , with "," will pretty much mess up your format. You are better off exporting with a different delimiter (something that really will not appear in your data - maybe a special character) and then doing your Replace on that

Comment: Thanks but the ticked answer above seems to work fine!